# Word find and replace using regex | alternation operator

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

While using regex for finding text, I am going wrong somewhere.

This is the code I am using.

```
findText = "(Event Handling|Event Handling \(EH\))"
Debug.Print findText
With Selection.Find
    .Text = findText
    .Replacement.Text = "Replaced"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .matchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

I am trying to find `Event Handling` or `Event Handling (EH)` in the passage, but the OR operator is not working.

When I try to find `Event Handling` separately, its working. similarly for `Event Handling (EH)`. But on together with the OR operator `|` it's not working. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Word's built-in Find functionality only supports a limited set of regular expressions. If you want to use the full, usual, standard regular expressions, you have to do something like this:

```
Dim regExp As Object
Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With regExp
    .Pattern = "(Event Handling \(EH\)|Event Handling)"
    .Global = True
    Selection.Text = .Replace(Selection.Text, "Replaced")
End With
```

If you select your passage and run this, text will be replaced as you intended. But note that `Event Handling \(EH\)` should come first in the search pattern alternation `"(Event Handling \(EH\)|Event Handling)"`, because if `Event Handling` comes first as you originally wrote it, it will get replaced first, leaving any `(EH)` behind.

Or, if you want to use Word's built-in `Find`, then just do two searches — and here too, `Event Handling \(EH\)` should be the first one:

```
'Settings
With Selection.Find
    .Replacement.text = "Replaced"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

'First find
With Selection.Find
    .text = "Event Handling \(EH\)"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

'Second find
With Selection.Find
    .text = "Event Handling"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Comment: sorry.. allMatches is the object right..how can i replace the matched content?

Comment: i have already used this two search method. I enable the track changes. so for the second time it replaces the track change content also. like this monoclonal antibodies(striked) MAb(MAb(striked))MAb

Comment: Ok, did you look at my edited Regexp code at the top of my answer.

Comment: its not working.. Is there any way in VBA to find except track change content??

Comment: Too long to address in a comment... I suggest you ask a new question. A screenshot illustrating your problem would help.

Comment: Is there any way to preserve the **Format** of the Selected Text after the replacement, when using the `regExp`?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word's Find & Replace does work with Regular Expressions of sorts, but only with a limited set of features. You need to click the Use Wildcards option in the "Advanced"/"More" dropdown pane.

This MVP article documents how to use this: [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)

Comment: Can you add the most relevant informations from this link into your answer?